# java.net.UnknownHostException:www.google.com

Tags: java, exception

I am developing a sanity check web application. I tried getting url response using HttpUrlConnection method but I am getting UnknownHostException.

```
 System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
    String[] uat_targetUrls={"https://www.google.com"};
    String[] uat_targetResponse=new String[uat_targetUrls.length];

            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn;
            httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uat_targetUrls[i])
            .openConnection();

            httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");


            httpUrlConn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            httpUrlConn.setReadTimeout(30000);



           if(httpUrlConn.getResponseCode()==200)
               uat_targetResponse[i]="UP";
           else 
               uat_targetResponse[i]="DOWN";
```

When executing this, I am getting UnknownHostException for various urls. Can anyone help me on this. I am using Eclipse IDE. This is the error I am getting:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to configure a proxy?

Comment: I am able to access the url through browser but not getting reply from host on ping.

Comment: What does Preferences > General > Network Connections in Eclipse look like?

Comment: I can see two sections : Proxy Entries and Proxy ByPass. There are 2 entries in Proxy ByPass->localhost and 127.0.0.1. In Proxy entries HTTP is checked.

Answer (score 2):

The problem must be a networking issue on your machine.

Your code works for me (with some minor fixes to repair the missing loop variable `i`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
    String[] uat_targetUrls = { "https://www.google.com" };
    String[] uat_targetResponse = new String[uat_targetUrls.length];

    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn;
    httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uat_targetUrls[0])
            .openConnection();

    httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    httpUrlConn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    httpUrlConn.setReadTimeout(30000);

    if (httpUrlConn.getResponseCode() == 200)
        uat_targetResponse[0] = "UP";
    else
        uat_targetResponse[0] = "DOWN";


    System.out.println(uat_targetResponse[0]);
}
```

Output: `UP`

Comment: Yeah that works for me too on my local machine. I am facing problem when using it from my organization's desktop. Do you have a fix for this.

Comment: @NikhileshTiwari This is the wrong site for help fixing your network issues, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

try pinging `www.google.com` 
using

```
ping www.google.com -t
```

if you get a time out error
Reason 1: No internet connection
Reason 2: You are probably behind an proxy server.
Reason 3: Add credentials to header

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code provided by you, It seems working fine. UnknownHostException is thrown when IP address is not resolved.
If you are in some organization, check if the network allows you to connect to network through code, or if DNS settings are proper.

Comment: I can access the url through my browser but when I am trying to ping the hostname it does not reply back.

Comment: can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser

If this helps?

Comment: Thanks Code Fighter, I tried changing my program using the solution given but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use ping www.google.com -4 to see if you can visit google.com by ipv4.