# UnknownHostException : google in connecting google cloud sql through app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

UnknownHostException : google error occurred in connecting google cloud sql through app engine.
Able to connect to my google cloud sql from app engine successfully and also by using proxy.

```
gcloud sql connect <My_INSTANCE_ID> --user=postgres
```

Is it some configuration misssing from my end ? Please help me out.

Below are the configuration

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://google/<MY_GOOLE_SQL_DB>?socketFactoryArg=<Instance_Connection name XX:XX:XX format>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.username=XXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX
```

Below are the pom related changes and use spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-sqladmin</artifactId>
    <version>v1beta4-rev57-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.60</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Below are the error logs .

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c0c903a.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c0c903a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$345dcf74.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c0c903a.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:109)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:693)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:655)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:625)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:819)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: google
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:156)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like socket library jar is not on the classpath.

Have you included Postgresql in pom something like this

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You can refer this, seems like similar case

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825442/java-net-unknownhostexceptionwww-google-com) question, you probably have a networking/local environment issue on your machine. According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/x91y1IV4rLQ) Google Groups thread, it may be for e.g. a firewall issue. Try connecting to a different Internet connection and then rerun the code.

Comment: I am in Google app engine. Their is no local environment.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by creating cloud sql proxy. 
After creating the proxy i am able to connect with google cloud sql

/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql &

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/tree/master/examples/postgres/appengine-standard-java8