# Http Request for API

Tags: java, apache, http, httprequest

I am learning to how to use http request. The following is the code which return JSON. All I am doing is to get it and print it. But I am facing some error. The error is also given below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ZipTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL stck = new URL("http://www.zipfeeder.us/zip?key=Ect9O9ta&zips=14623");
        URLConnection yc = stck.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String add="";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(inputLine);
            add=add+inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(add);

    }

}
```

This is the error. In my old machine this code worked perfectly fine. I just got a new machine this week. The same code is now not working. previously I was using jdk 1.7 and now i am using jdk 1.8

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.zipfeeder.us/zip?key=Ect9O9ta&zips=14623
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at ZipTester.main(ZipTester.java:11)
```

Comment: A 403 signifies that you are forbidden to access that entity.

Comment: your new box have firewall enabled?

Comment: yes my firewall is on. How do i correct this error then ?

Comment: @TMcKeown Doesn't the 403 response code indicate the request is getting to the server?

Comment: ah!  yes.. then it's the creds of the request...

Comment: http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/?symbol=AAPL 
I tried it with this other URL and it works fines. So what exactly was the problem ?

Comment: Try with `https://www.zipfeeder.us` if that doesn't work, contact their support.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code with adding user-agent header like this :

```
yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",""); //to avoid 403 error
```

The website had probably change it access rules and now it request a "user-agent".

The full code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ZipTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL stck = new URL("http://www.zipfeeder.us/zip?key=Ect9O9ta&zips=14623");
        URLConnection yc = stck.openConnection();
        yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",""); //to avoid 403 error
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String add="";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            add=add+inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(add);

    }

}
```

I hope it will help you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting the user agent with a following value:

```
yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
```