# Get image from server to imageview

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I use Free Hosting EU: 
http://cp1.freehostingeu.com/

Uploaded my image but I can't display it in imageview, getting empty by using Picasso.
When I browse url of image which is like

```
http://example.me.pn/Upload_Images/uploadedimages/9_images.jpeg
```

it gets

> ERROR 403: FORBIDDEN WEB PAGE

What is the problem in my host or code?

I use this:

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).centerCrop().resize(150,150).into(navMainProfile);
```

Comment: Probably it's a problem in server. Can you access the image from a browser (with direct url)? And, if you want, add the image url to your question

Comment: no i cant, here is url http://hrguide.me.pn/Upload_Images/uploadedimages/9_images.jpeg

Comment: If you can't access image on browser it's not an Android or Picasso problem. Solve the access problem on your server and it'll probably solve your issue on Android

Comment: what should i do for be accessing image in server

Comment: I don't know your current server settings or if your image upload actually succeeded. 403 is a generic server error, so I have no idea what's going on. Try uploading image again, check if upload was correct and if url is right

Comment: im using free host. is that a problem

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser