# Why do I always get 403 when fetching data with RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to fetch data but always getting `403(Forbidden)` with `RestTemplate`.

But when I try `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` instead, everything is OK. I'm also able to get data with Postman on my machine.

The code is quite simple but I don't know what's wrong.

```
public Object get() {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            Object result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/19776/enUS/cards.json", Object.class);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: appending **stack trace**

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
    at com.brawlstone.metaservice.service.SyncService.get(SyncService.java:49)
    at com.brawlstone.metaservice.web.SyncController.getCards(SyncController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try to add a "User-Agent" header to your request.

Change your code to:

```
try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

            Object response = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/19776/enUS/cards.json", HttpMethod.GET,entity,Object.class);

            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: It works! But why am I able to get data by "curl -X GET https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/19776/enUS/cards.json
" ? There's no user-agent in the command.

Comment: Try "curl -v https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/19776/enUS/cards.json" from command line, you can see the list of complete headers and other info. You can see "User-Agent: curl/7.52.1".

Comment: Do you have some documentation/explanation about this solution?

Comment: @user7294900 the explanation is given here :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser

Answer (score 18):

**You are trying to access `https` without configuring `RestTemplate` to use any SSL certificate for request**

Try to use following configuration of `RestTemplate`

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
Object result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/19776/enUS/cards.json", Object.class);
....
```

Comment: it works ! Thank you! But when I change url to "https://api.github.com", I remove the configuration about ssl and I'm still able to get result successfully. Why is the difference?

Comment: I think github api server having option to accept request without SSL/TLS handshake but the api.hearthstonejson server don't.

Comment: actually, it is a bad practice. This code told HTTP client to trust every certificate, so some sense of https is lost. That's why a man in the middle could easily intercept your communication and you won't know about that.

Comment: It works. but I have added 

   'CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                    .build()'

using httpClient 4.4v

Comment: This should be valid accepted answer!