# SpringBoot RestTemplate return 403 forbidden when executing from docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, resttemplate, http-status-code-403

I am trying to implement Spring Boot RestTemplate and invoke external REST service using Java Code. This is working as java application but when I am **deploying same code in docker container** I am getting error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [error code: 1010]
```

Here is my code ..which is running standalone ..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/extservice", 
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User httpcall() {
        
        ResponseEntity<User> result = null;
         
        try {
             
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
            final String uri = "https://reqres.in/api/users/2";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
             
            result = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, User.class);
             
            System.out.println(result.toString());
         

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return result.getBody();

    }
```

and here is the error stack trace

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [error code: 1010]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:342)
    at com.dockerforjavadevelopers.hello.HelloController.httpcall(HelloController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

....

2020-07-25 04:52:17.578 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9898-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/opa-test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.dockerforjavadevelopers.hello.HelloController.httpcall(HelloController.java:48) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Here is my docker file

```
# Maven build container 

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim as mavenbuild

COPY pom.xml /tmp/

COPY src /tmp/src/

WORKDIR /tmp/

RUN mvn package

#pull base image

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

EXPOSE 9898

#default command
CMD java -jar /data/opa-test-0.1.0.jar

#copy hello world to docker image from builder image

COPY --from=mavenbuild /tmp/target/opa-test-0.1.0.jar /data/opa-test-0.1.0.jar
```

Comment: Can you show the docker file

Comment: Added in question .. for reference .. i am able to access ping method from the same microservice ..and it is returning the response ..

Comment: Can you curl that `endpoint` which you're trying to call via `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Plus kindly see this as you're using `HTTPS`, [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44922564/6332074) might be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to do it ..but surprising it is working when running as application [ not in container ] but failing in docker container

Comment: Can you try to run your container with `--net=host`

Comment: htst network can not be used here as we are deploying it in kubernetes cluster with istio

Answer (score 2):

You have created the **HttpHeaders** object but don't used.
Please use exchange method of RestTemplate.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("user-agent", "Application");
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> responseJson = restTemplate.exchange(resourceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Yesh faced a similar issue as reported in the OP.
Adding headers with content type jSON seemed to fix the issue