# Java reading URL from anapioficeandfire returns 403

Tags: java, http, url

I want to get Json from https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/583 with native Java

Here is the code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/583");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

What I get is this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/583
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at sprint2.fireandice.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

This code works with example.com, google.com etc...

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser should help you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `openStream()`. The server rejects this Connection and sends 403 Forbidden. You can "fool" the server and act like a normal browser by setting a user-agent.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    URL oracle = new URL("https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/583");
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();
    httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it worked even without typing .openConnection() to (HttpURLConnection).


URLConnection myUrlConnection =  myUrl.openConnection();
myUrlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");

Comment: Awesome answer, I knew it was something to do with the server thinking I was doing something wrong. I just did not know what to look for.

Comment: Amazon cloudfront requires httpcon.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");