# Java http request GET causes timeout exception while it works fine in the browser

Tags: java, http, https, socket-timeout-exception, okhttp

I have been playing with `Http` in `Java` and I faced a strange problem. Below is a piece code which executes `GET` method:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Response response = null;
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.celebritycruises.com/")
        .get()
        .build();
try {
    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So there are some sites (like the one provided in the `Builder` which cause:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
[...]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)

at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
... 38 more
```

What I do NOT understand is: why this works fine in the browser? I already set `timeouts` for `100seconds`. I also tried with other HttpClients but with the same results (I believe deep down they use same classes anyways). Could anyone tell me where the problem lies, please?

## Edit

I tried `wget` - worked, saved some HTML content.
`curl` returned: `(52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: What is Okio? It can be related

Comment: I use OkHttpClient so I assume Okio is some `OK`-`Input-Output` kind-of-thing.

Comment: Relayed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670692/403-forbidden-with-java-but-not-web-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an User-Agent in your request. This works:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.celebritycruises.com/").header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0").build();
```

Comment: Okay, this solved this exact problem. Could you please explain why?

Comment: Probably the web is rejecting connections without User-Agent. They should return a response code 400 or 403 instead.