# Java ImageIO.read() crashes if url contains special characters

Tags: java, javax.imageio

In my Java app, I want to download an image using the following:

```
ImageIO.read(new URL("https://www.example.com/example.png"))
```

It works fine most of the time, except for this url: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*XSCC_nLOSp1VJ6wXeANgCQ.png

The problem in the url is that there is an * in it. So I try the following workarounds, without any success:

- replacing the * by \*
- replacing the * by %2A

I always have the following error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1395)
```

How can I download the image, then?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't think an asterisk was allowed in filenames?

Comment: try URLEncoder.encode

Comment: @SteveSmith Me neither, but here we are

Comment: @HenningLuther Thanks, but it doesn't encode the * unfortunately...

Comment: You could have a look at the source for ImageIO.read() and see what it does.

Comment: @SteveSmith It call URL.openStream(), and here is where the crash occurs.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? I get this issue on Java 8, but not on Java 11.

Comment: Try using the solution as specified here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671432/2796463. This seems to fix the issue for me.

Comment: @DragonAssassin ok, I'll try, thanks!

Comment: @DragonAssassin That’s definitely the issue.  It’s probably worth making into an answer, with an ImageIO-compatible solution.

Comment: @DragonAssassin Yes, as soon as I manage make my project work again, because it's completely upside down for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to Java 8 and is fixed in Java 11. The problem with Java 8 is that a HTTP 403 code is returned.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*XSCC_nLOSp1VJ6wXeANgCQ.png
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1393)
```

To fix this we need to set the user agent header.

```
URL url = new URL("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*XSCC_nLOSp1VJ6wXeANgCQ.png");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
connection.connect();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, using Java 11 only solved the problem.